# QML Drag & drop in a grid

Tags: drag-and-drop, qml

I have an item (a rectangle) which can be moved through the different positions of the grid (see code below).

The reference to decide whether the rectangle is in one cell or another is the top-left (x=0;y=0) of the rectangle. I want the reference to be the center of the rectangle. Any ideas?

Find the code below:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtPositioning 5.5
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQml 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Rectangle{
id: mainContainer
width:800; height:width
color: "red"

Grid {
id:gridA
anchors.centerIn: parent
width: parent.width; height:width;
columns: 2; rows: 2; spacing: 2

verticalItemAlignment: Grid.AlignHCenter
horizontalItemAlignment: Grid.AlignVCenter

Repeater {
id:cells
model: gridA.columns*gridA.rows
property int draggedItemIndex: -1

Rectangle {

width: gridA.width/gridA.columns; height: gridA.height/gridA.rows
color: "white"

DropArea {
    id: dragTarget
    property alias dropProxy: dragTarget
    anchors.fill: parent
    keys: [ "KEY_A" ]

    Rectangle {
        id: dropRectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        states: [
            State {
                when: dragTarget.containsDrag
                PropertyChanges { target: dropRectangle; color: "grey"}
                PropertyChanges { target: cells; draggedItemIndex: index}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
}

Rectangle{
id: icon
property var draggedIndex: 0

width: parent.width/3; height:width
color:"blue"
Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
Drag.keys: [ "KEY_A" ]

MouseArea {
    id: dragArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    drag.target: icon
    cursorShape: drag.active ? Qt.ClosedHandCursor : Qt.OpenHandCursor
        onReleased: {
            console.log("Drag: " + cells.draggedItemIndex)
            if (cells.draggedItemIndex != icon.draggedIndex) {
                icon.draggedIndex = cells.draggedItemIndex
                cells.draggedItemIndex = -1
            }
            icon.x = cells.itemAt(icon.draggedIndex).x
            icon.y = cells.itemAt(icon.draggedIndex).y
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image: drag and drop reference]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `Drag`-attached property, which has the [`hotSpot`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-drag.html#hotSpot-attached-prop)-property of type `PointF`.

Set this property to `Qt.point(width / 2, height / 2)`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see it :)